# Entity Framework Transaction code blocks

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I'm running some complex stuff and trying to reduce the time certain transactions take as they appear to be timing out but i'm not sure what the impact is of making the following change.

so assuming I'm using ...

```
var scope = new TransactionScope(
   TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
   DefaultTransactionOptions, 
   TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled
);
```

Sample 1:

```
using (scope)
{

   // get stuff from multiple db's
   // make a bunch of changes to entities
   Db1.Savechanges(); 
   Db2.Savechanges();
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Sample 2:

```
   // get stuff from multiple db's
   // make a bunch of changes to entities

using (scope)
{
   Db1.Savechanges(); 
   Db2.Savechanges();
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Are these going to do the same thing ?

My gut feeling is that they should but I may be able to reduce my timeouts by not doing all the CPU bound stuff and keeping the transaction for the bit i care about (data continuity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference, but not for the saves.  However, I think as soon as you declare scope, everything going forward will fall under it.  Thus, you want to declare it in the using statement at the very end.  Otherwise, all the get commands will be in the transaction scope, possibly locking records depending on the settings.  However, when it comes to the timeout during the save call itself, there won't be any difference as the timeout is normally a single DB failure, not the total amount of the transaction scope.  Transaction Scope uses the Machine config setting as the maximum timeout. The default machine timeout is 10 minutes.  Thus, one of the db SaveChanges call itself is probably greater than the default 30 second connection so the TransactionScope isn't the issue.

Comment: Yeh I noticed the timeout too so I declared a constant (as all my services use the same transaction options anyway) in that i tried setting the timeout to say 1 hour and it still seems to timeout after 10 minutes. This post has sort of turned in to an XY problem as I figured the solution was to "save time inside the transaction" by not including all those get calls and other none db related business logic

Comment: if you are saving a lot of records with EF, you may want to try another approach. EF slows way down when you go beyond 100 records.  I often just create many threads that save 1 record at a time, but they each create their own dbcontext. If it is a lot of adds, I would look into bulk insert, too.

Comment: Hi daniel, sorry for the delay I got pulled off on to something else, any idea how I would do EF style bulk updates and inserts to an object graph without EF?

Comment: There are 3rd party Nuget packages that add bulk support directly to EF but you can use the built in one for SQL server via ado.net. you can use the entity directly to generate the Datatable it needs since you know the column name and type.  or you have to create a transaction and just save 20 at a time.